# macro to add value in cells corresponding to same category

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to macro-VBA . It  could be very helpful if some one could guide me in the following.

I have a data-set that has category name in column A and in column B the corresponding values. 
[It looks somewhat like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7zi7.jpg)

Based on the category name in column A, I should get a sum of values present in B. that is if cells A1:A3 belongs to category "a", values present in B1:B3 should be summed and the corresponding rows should be merged in column C and the resultant sum should be displayed in column C 
[Output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bok97.jpg)

I tried to code using in the following way

```
Sub main()
Dim i As Long
Dim a As Long '

Dim sum As Long
sum = 0
Dim samerows As Boolean
samerows = True
For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If StrComp(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1), vbTextCompare) Then
        samerows = False
    End If

    If samerows Then
        sum = sum + Cells(i, 1).Value
        Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i + 1, 2)).Merge
    End If

    samerows = True
    Cells(i, 2).Value = sum
Next i

End Sub
```

But this code is wrong as I am unable to provide proper cell reference values.

It would be of great help, if some one could share their thoughts and guide me with a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to keep as close to your style as code as possible, I added a count of the number of cells that is needed to ensure that you reference the top left cell in any field of merged cells (as this is where Excel stores the values), as well as added a few more summary instances. Please try the following:

```
Sub main()
Dim i As Long
Dim a As Long '

Dim sum As Long
Dim mergeCnt As Long
mergeCnt = 0
sum = 0
Dim samerows As Boolean
samerows = True
For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If StrComp(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1), vbTextCompare) Then
        sum = sum + Cells(i, 2).Value
        samerows = False
    End If
    Debug.Print (sum)
    If samerows Then
        sum = sum + Cells(i, 2).Value
        Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i + 1, 3)).Merge
        mergeCnt = mergeCnt + 1
    Else:
        Cells(i - mergeCnt, 3).Value = sum
        sum = 0
        mergeCnt = 0
    End If

    samerows = True
    Cells(i, 3).Value = sum
Next i

End Sub
```